# All warning lights came on, the odometer did not.

Tags: electrical, ford, f-150, pick-up

I have a 2008 F150 160k miles and all of the warning lights came on (Check engine,  ABS, low tire, parking brake, 4x4 Hi and 4x4 Low from what I remember). The odometer was just a blank green screen.  I turned the truck off and the radio didn't turn off like it normally does when I open the door.  After turning it on and of a few times it was fixed.  This is the first time it happened sobe I bought it a month and a half ago from a big dealership,  but it has so many miles they sold it "as is." I did get them to replace the catalytic converter 2 weeks after I bought it.  It's been almost a month since then and this happened. Also, I don't know if this is related, but I noticed recently my front windows are starting to be difficult when rolling up,  not down.  What could be the issue with the dashboard? I tried providing as much information as I could.

Comment: Does it start and run okay?

Comment: Yeah. I didn't Dobie it like that because I turned it on and of a few times and then it went away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like the fault is within the instrument binnacle or associated wiring as opposed to the lights being genuine warning lights.  It sounds like a classic "shorting out" problem.  This could be caused by a loose connection or poorly installed accessory (immobilizer, aftermarket radio, etc...)

I'd be inclined to start checking wiring plugs are firmly fixed in place.  Also look for signed of water ingress as rain water leaking onto the circuits could cause a short.

Comment: I haven't installed anything.  I'm thinking it has to do something with the ignition because when it's doing it and the key is out and the doors are open the windows and radio still works as if the key was in.

Comment: It happened again for the third time. I smacked the dashboard right above the gauges and it started working properly.

Comment: @kingcobra1986 That's great that you've somewhat identified the problem and a quick fix!  But plan (and save money) for when the smack no longer fixes because that time will come sooner than expected.

Answer (score 2):

This can be the key cylinder switch or the harness connector at the other end. These are known to come loose. Find the large harness coming off the key cylinder and follow it all the way to the firewall. Check any connector you come to by opening it, checking for moisture and corrosion, and reassembling it. Check the large firewall connectors as well.

If your in the US check your local laws for implied warranty of merchant-ability. AKA lemon law or implied warranty. Most states have 3 years but some have limits on used vehicles.

Comment: @DucatiKiller  Ignition switch is a bit of a misnomer. In a 2008 all of the ignition switching is handled by relays. The Key switch is a multi-function switch. Controlling Ignition Relays, Accessories, and Starter.

Answer (score 0):

Alternator may be going bad. Low voltage or wrong voltage will cause gauges to misread data and the slow windows indicate low voltage.